# zarr not respecting chunk size from xarray and reverting to original chunk size

Tags: python, python-xarray, zarr

I'm opening a zarr file and then rechunking it and then writing it back out to a different zarr store. Yet when I open it back up it doesn't respect the chunk size I previously wrote. Here is the code and the output from jupyter. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
bathy_ds = xr.open_zarr('data/bathy_store')
bathy_ds.elevation
```

[image]

```
bathy_ds.chunk(5000).elevation
```

[image]

```
bathy_ds.chunk(5000).to_zarr('data/elevation_store')
new_ds = xr.open_zarr('data/elevation_store')
new_ds.elevation
```

[image]

It is reverting back to the original chunking as if I'm not fully overwriting it or changing some other setting that needs changing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be a known [issue](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/5219), and there's a fair bit of discussion going on within the issue's thread and a [recently merged PR](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/pull/5065).

Basically, the dataset carries the original chunking around in the `.encoding` property. So when you call the second write operation, the chunks defined in `ds[var].encoding['chunks']` (if present) will be used to write `var` to zarr.

According to the conversation in the GH issue, the currently best solution is to manually delete the chunk encoding for the variables in question:

```py
for var in ds:
    del ds[var].encoding['chunks']
```

However, it should be noted that this seems to be an evolving situation, where it's be good to check in on the progress to adapt a final solution.

Here's a little example that showcases the issue and solution:

```py
import xarray as xr

# load data and write to initial chunking 
x = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature")
x.chunk({"time":500, "lat":-1, "lon":-1}).to_zarr("zarr1.zarr")

# display initial chunking
xr.open_zarr("zarr1.zarr/").air
```

[image]

```py
# rechunk
y = xr.open_zarr("zarr1.zarr/").chunk({"time": -1})

# display
y.air
```

[image]

```py
#write w/o modifying .encoding
y.to_zarr("zarr2.zarr")

# display
xr.open_zarr("zarr2.zarr/").air
```

[image]

```py
# delete encoding and store
del y.air.encoding['chunks']
y.to_zarr("zarr3.zarr")

# display
xr.open_zarr("zarr3.zarr/").air
```

[image]